# Url rewrite not working for .com/index?foo=value to .com/value

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Here is my rewrite, what is it I'm doing wrong?

The starting result:

```
www.website.com/index?foo=value
```

The desired result:

```
www.website.com/value
```

Code:

```
    # Redirect /index.php to /index
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(index)\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ / [R=302,L]
    # Redirect /page.php?foo=value to /page/value
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(index)\.php\?foo=([^\s]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /%2? [R=302,L]
    # Internally forward /value to /index.php?foo=value
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /index.php?foo=$1 [L,QSA]
```

EDIT: I updated the code to what it currently is. The current issue now is adding a prameter to the end sends me to a 404 page instead of seeing it as a query parameter

www.website.com/value -> 404

Comment: `RewriteRule ^/(.*)?$ /$1.php?foo=$2 [L,QSA,NC]` does exactly the opposite of what you're asking.

Comment: That's just the forward letting it know to view /value the same as index.php?foo=value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last rule should be:

```
# Internally forward /value to /index.php?foo=value
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /index.php?foo=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Is my redirect also wrong then? It seems to not be seeing foo as a parameter but an actual file//folder, 

www.website.com/value in this instance keeps sending me to a 404 page

Comment: Yes your last rule should be as I suggested above. If `/value` is not a file/directory then it will be rewritten to `/index.php?foo=value`

Comment: Okay I should clarify, this works properly as far as the index.php page is concerned. Whenever I go to one of my other pages though it changes the url to the write thing but keeps you on index.php. Its not recognizing it as an actual file/directory.

Is this because I have a rewrite for pages to strip off the .php? If so, whats the fix I need?

Comment: Nevermind, it hit me as soon as I hit add comment. I had to change the order of my rewrites! Thank you so much.

Comment: I also have a www.domain.com/games/index.php?puzzle=value. Is there a way to make this rewrite not effect it? or do I need to write a new redirect all together for this?

Comment: This rewrite won't affect any URL that is for a valid file/directory. So if `/games/index.php` is a valid file then above rule won't affect it.